# How to respond to interview offers while employed?

Tags: interviewing, scheduling

I'm presently employed, after only 6 months I know it's not a place I should stay for long, I should get out as soon as I can.

I don't earn a ton of vacation time and it's not appropriate to use sick time, except maybe a wellness day about every 2-3 months.

I can usually get a couple hours off at the end of the day for a phone/video interview but it's not always easy to get a half-day for an in-person interview, though it can be done.

I don't want to make/set any obvious patterns, so it seems like I want to learn how to ask an employer for a phone/video interview starting at 400 or 430 pm...is this reasonable to request????

Any/all suggestions how to ask a potential employer for accommodations in terms of the timing of the interview events would be helpful, it is also so I can try to actually get work done despite the current employer not being very good etc.

Thank you, :) P

Comment: Time off isn't pooled, sick is sick, anything else is basically vacation time, even a wellness day is sick time. Sort of more old school-ish and I don't want to abuse vacation time requests.

Answer (score 5):

> so it seems like I want to learn how to ask an employer for a phone/video interview starting at 400 or 430 pm...is this reasonable to request????

**Yes, that sounds absolutely reasonable.**

This time slot is during normal business hour. So, it should be OK. However, please make sure that the interviewers are in the same time zone as yours.

If you and the interviewers are not in the same time zone, then 4 PM in your time zone might be 5 PM, 6 PM, or 7 PM in their time zone.

Sometimes, some interviewers can work from 5 PM to 6 PM to interview a candidate. This has happened in my experience. You just need to ask the persons who schedule the interview. They will let you know when the interviewers are available.

Comment: **If you and the interviewers are not in the same time zone, then 4 PM in your time zone might be 5 PM, 6 PM, or 7 PM in their time zone.** - OP could then ask for calls before the start of their working day potentially?

Answer (score 4):

Any reasonable hiring manager understands that people who're currently working can't always interview during standard working hours and will make accommodations to either do things during the lunch hour or after the close of normal office hours if needed.

If you can't easily take time off during the working day, just say so.  If they can't accommodate your request, it's up to you to decide if you want to burn one of your limited abilities to take a few hours off during working hours, but it's a red flag that they'll likely also be unreasonable if you need to take a few hours for personal reasons if hired.

Answer (score 3):

As a former hiring engineering manager, I believe that scheduling interviews later in the workday is very reasonable, especially if you provide the reason that you aren't available during the workday due to professional obligations. If I wanted to interview you, I would make it work. Remember, interviews are a two-way street. You are not at the company's beck and call, so you can have input into when you meet with them.

Early in my career, I was in a similar situation, and the interviewing company invited me to dinner for the interview. It worked for both of us, was more casual, and not only did I get an offer, but I also scored a nice meal out of it too.

Answer (score 2):

Interview dates are negotiable. Talk with them about finding a mutually convenient date and time.

Answer (score 2):

What is your work from home policy like? If you have WFH days, you can (maybe, depending on your role) chance using those and get your actual work done later. Won't work if you're expected to be in meetings though.

This will be much easier to do if you're doing remote interviews